# Upload a single file in Web API

Tags: c#, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using this code to upload file in Web API. But my posted file is showing Null. Perhaps it is because the code is expecting multiple files in postman. I need to uplaod a single file through postman and not the list of files. I am sharing the code.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(string targetIdStr, string feedType, 
    string contentType, string dateCreated, string description, List<IFormFile> files)
```

Comment: how the code in client submit your file?

Answer (score 2):

For uploading one file, you need to change Action like below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(string targetIdStr, string feedType,
  string contentType, string dateCreated, string description, IFormFile file)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

For request in PostMan, Send request with post->Set Body as `form-data` like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll give you a real web api controller on how you can upload a single file. Class below is a working example. Just replace the constant value with a small file on your disk.

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        private const string FILEPATH = @"c:\temp\demo.txt";

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult JsonObject()
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(FILEPATH);
            return new OkObjectResult(new FileClass()
            {
                Name = file.Name,
                Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FILEPATH)
            });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index([FromBody] FileClass file)
        {
            return new NoContentResult();
        }
    }

    public class FileClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now in postman first launch the call to the get uri
https://localhost:44382/api/upload

This will result in a json answer showing you the json you need to return in my case this was:

```
{
    "name": "demo.txt",
    "content": "dGVzdCBkYXRh"
}
```

In postman now choose the option post and in the body choose raw and paste the get result in it and launch it.
When in debug you'll now see that the json object has arrived.
Screenshot below shows the postman proof that it works:
[image: PostMan Example]

Comment: What Chris wrote highlights all the things that were not good in the original web api call.
See his answer for the reason why I did my implementation like this and you should be on your way creating whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of problems here. First, the action method signature will only ever work with `multipart/form-data` encoded requests. In order to accept something like JSON, you have to apply the `[FromBody]` attribute to a param, which you can only do once. In other words, if you want to accept something like JSON, you need a class that encompasses all these params, allowing you to accept just that class as a param, with the `[FromBody]` attribute.

Also, if you hope to accept something like JSON, you cannot bind to `IFormFile` (or `List<IFormFile>`) because that also only works for `multipart/form-data` encoded requests. Instead, you must bind to a `byte[]`, and on the client side, you would need to convert the file to a base64-encoded string to include in the JSON object.

If you are actually intending on accepting only `multipart/form-data` encoded requests (which is odd for an API), then you simply need to ensure that the file in the post body is associated with the correct name of `files[]`, i.e. indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you create your client side code, I assume you are using FormData in JavaScript?
[JavaScript API FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

JS code is something like this?

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("file", "the file name");
form_data.append("fileID", file_id)
var sendMethod = './Upload';  //this is the url for post
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: sendMethod,
  data: form_data,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (response) {
      //......
},
error: function (response) {
      //......
}
);
```

Server Side,

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, int fileID
{
  //......
}
```

I didn't the test the code above, but it should work and hope it helps.